# Modem distracting radio signal?

Tags: radio, wifi

Ok I have Internet modem connected to tv and also radio player (with CD and cassette player) under tv, as soon I turn on modem radio can't produce clear sound and when turned of radio sound is great. So is it possible that modem or maybe WiFi is distracting radio waves so I can't "catch" radio station? Is that sign of modem getting faulty?
I'm not really interested in fixing this problem, that can be achieved probably by moving one of them. I'm just interested in this distracting is it ok or what? I know that modems shouldn't be near microwave for reason I forgot (probably micro waves duh), but never heard of this problem, also everything was fine until some time ago when radio was for few days in other room and than I put it back Bellow tv.

Comment: Why would you connect your modem to the tv?

Comment: @PlasmaHH because it's kind of smart TV but don't have option to connect wirelessly, but only via cable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly caused by cheap, crappy electronics that either have poor immunity or give out unwanted emissions. It is not a sign of "something" breaking, but rather a certain sign that "something" was never properly designed to begin with.

As for which of your devices that is the culprit... if the "radio" is an old FM/AM radio, it is very likely to blame, as these are infamous for their poor immunity characteristics. Most likely it was never designed to sit close to a radio transmitter such as your modem.

At the same time, your *other* radio receiver, commonly known as a TV, seems to work just fine despite the modem. Because it was properly designed.

A crappy radio design will not filter out received emissions on other frequencies, but rather "absorb" these signals into itself. This in turn will disturb the analog circuits inside the radio, resulting in noise. A wireless modem spits out quite a bit of energy, so the closer to the modem you place the radio, the more likely it will disturb.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation, probably radio had low durability since it worked fine at first. Well in this case I better move modem even from tv even if it should have durability since it have option to connect to modem, however I doubt in that durability.